# Problems to load VennDiagram package for R version 2.13.0

Tags: r, plot, venn-diagram

I want use the **VennDiagram** package to correlate three different variables. But in R (version 2.13.0) the package is unavailable. I tried to install it from CRAN and generates this warning:

```
Installing package(s) into ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.13/Resources/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘VennDiagram’ is not available (for R version 2.13.0)
```

Also, I tried to use venneuler but in this case I did not show the labels of the different areas, this is the result:

[image: Venn diagram of different ncRNAs shared between three different species]

Some suggestions?

Comment: 2.13 is a bit old. You might want to upgrade R

Comment: I use MacOS Snow Leopard and I run R from Rstudio, How can I upgrade R from this program? or by other way?

Comment: Cristian, please read the fine manual "R Installation and Administration" that came with your R version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CRAN page of VennDiagram shows that the package needs at least R 2.14 to work. There are three solutions I can think of:

- Update R, R 2.13 is old.
- Download the source of VennDiagram and edit the DESCRIPTION file. Replace the requirement of R 2.14 by an R version lower than the one you have, and install the package from source (R CMD INSTALL from the command line). This will only work if the package does not use any features that are only available in R 2.14 and above.
- Go to the archive of the package on CRAN and download a version of the package compatible with R 2.13 (thanks Dirk).

Comment: Third solution:  Go to the CRAN Archive directory for the package and install a version corresponding to R 2.13.0. That is of course *a really bad solution* and upgrading R itself is preferable.

Comment: I agree, but in some cases one could be restricted to a certain version of R. I don't think this holds for the OP.

Comment: I added your solution to the list.

Comment: I came across the restricted R version problem with people using a commercial R application. +1 for a thoroughg and thoughtful answer.

Comment: Good solution. The upgrade solves the incompatibility. Thanks a lot!